# Is there a way to change the table column name in TDengine?

Tags: tdengine

I am using TDengine as my time-series storage engine and I want to change a column name of a super table. I tried to find a way in the official documents but I failed. Is there a way to change the column name of a super table?

Answer (score 0):

Change column name is not supported in TDengine 2.x.
TDengine 2.x supports add a new column, drop an existing column, change column length for binary/nchar column.

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm afraid not. Currently TDengine 2.x does not support column name changing. You can

1. Use `alter` to drop it and add a new column with the right name, but you may lost data.
2. Use `select col as col2` to use as you have a column `col2`, but does not work in `insert`s.